# SQL SERVER - I think Chinese hackers try to hack my SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

I run mssql server on ubuntu and sometimes the mssql service is fallen and my hosted app stops to work.

Looking at the error log and running Profiler I found these errors:

```
2019-10-08 13:27:47.64 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
2019-10-08 13:27:47.64 Logon       Login failed for user 'mssqla'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 123.125.125.248]

2019-10-08 13:27:46.32 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2019-10-08 13:27:46.32 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 123.125.125.248]

2019-10-08 13:28:57.13 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
2019-10-08 13:28:57.13 Logon       Login failed for user 'usera'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 123.125.125.248]
```

The users `usera` and `mssqla` don't exist and never were and I checked the ip address location and it shows it's origin is from China.

**Profiler trace results:**
[image]

I search the process id in my ubuntu using the command
`sudo ps -A` and processes not exist.

Am I being paranoid or someone from China tries to hack my Database and how can I stop him?

Comment: Yes, you are being hacked from China.  Where is your SQL Server instance located?  Is it on premise somewhere or in the cloud (e.g. on AWS)?  Basically, you need to put a proxy in front of your DB instance which will only allow certain IP addresses through (e.g. the IP address of your application).

Comment: Not just China. When you expose SQL Server to the public internet, you will have script kiddies trying to hack in continuously. Is there a reason you want anyone in the world accessing your server over the internet? If not, consider appropriate firewall rules, VPN, etc.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My sqlserver is on the server with my web application, I host them in Digital Ocean's New york.
What can I do to prevent these bastards?

Comment: @DanGuzman I am not sure I understand what you are saying, I have my database and the my web-app on the same server, my web application uses the database with `localhost`, what can I do to prevent external access from those Chinese?

Comment: This either sounds like you have your port `1433` (or whatever SQL Server is running on) open to the world (a foolish idea if I am honest), or you have a major injection issue going on. If the latter, then you'll want to take your website off line and fix every single piece of code that isn't **properly** parametrised, and then put it back online.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Larnu, I was naive ;(